# Chef kitchen.local.yml "attributes:" overrides sticking after removed

Tags: overriding, chef-infra, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I have this issue with chef, namely `kitchen.local.yml`.

It overrides `kitchen.yml`, that works.

But when I remove the overridden attribute, it behaves like it is not removed. It looks like it is somehow cached.

I can only change the value. This causes issues because i can't get the default attribute coming from the `attributes/*.rb`.

This is `.kitchen.local.yml`:

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list: [ "recipe[bbcpd-bpds-api]" ]
    attributes: {
      "bbcpd-bpds-api": {
        "redis": {
          #"host": "${REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:-10.0.2.2FOOO}",

          ###  This above seems to stick even though commented out.
          ###  Changing it FOOO to BAAR works.
          ###  But removing keeps the BAAR appearing 
          ###  unless I `kitchen destroy` and recreate again.
        }
     }
```

I didn't find the `FOOO` value on host machine except for the commented out line and logs.

On the guest machine (VM), I found it in `/tmp`:

```
kitchen/dna.json:{"bbcpd-bpds-api":{"update_mode":true,"redis":{"dbIndex":"12","host":"${REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:-10.0.2.2FOOO}"},"storage":{"ccr":{"url":"https://ccr-dev-citc.bbcollab.com/v1","client":"BPDS-Client-Id","secret":"ABCDEFGHABCDEFGHABCDEFGHABCDEFGHABCDEFGHunzoneunzoneunzoneunzoneunzoneunzoneunzoneunzone","tokenexpiry":"60","site":"Dev","container":"DevBPDSContainer"}},"libreoffice":{"binary":"/opt/libreoffice5.4/program/soffice"}},"run_list":["recipe[bbcpd-bpds-api]"]}

kitchen/nodes/default-centos-72.json:        "host": "${REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:-10.0.2.2FOOO}",
```

I am not quite sure what is the role of these, but I suspected these are somehow involved in keeping the state.

I have tried to delete `/tmp` but then, `kitchen converge` stopped working. It needed `kitchen create` to fix. But the `...FOOO` value appeared there again.

Running `kitchen destroy && kitchen create` makes the value go away, but since there is no caching for the VM base image, it takes around 15 minutes, so I would like to avoid it.

**Questions:**

1. Where are these values being cached so that they stick even after removed from `.kitchen.local.yml`?
2. How can I disable/clear that caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how it works, sorry. You have to destroy and recreate the instance to see changes in attribute settings.